# Printing each line of a file out

Tags: python

```
file = open(filename, 'r') 

a = 1
for i in file:
    print(str(a) + ': ' + str(i))
    a += 1
```

I am trying to print each line of the file out. yet as I print it the output is:

1: 9874234,12.5,23.0,50.0

2: 7840231,70,60,85.4

3: 3845913,55.5,60.5,80.0

4: 3849511,20,60,50

This is the correct output but I want to remove the extra lines between each output so there is no space between each output

Comment: Use `strip()` with `i`.  `print(str(a) + ': ' + i.strip())`

Comment: note that `str(i)` does nothing. `i` is already a string.

Comment: cheers. that worked thanks

Comment: @kuro: `strip() `will also strip any leading whitespace, as well as any whitespace that might also be present before the new line character(s). This may not be desired.

Comment: You are right. In that case one can use `rstrip('\n')`

Comment: @kuro: that's OK if lines are terminated by `\n`, i.e. unix format, or the file was opened in universal new line mode in Python 2 (universal new line mode is default in Python 3). If the file uses Windows or Mac newline conventions `rstrip('\n')` might fail, e.g. leave a stray `\r` for Windows and do nothing for Mac files.

Answer (score 2):

Your lines already end with a linebreak. `print` is adding another one.

Use `print(argument, end='')`.

If you want to streamline your code, you should look into the `enumerate` built in function.

Comment: I think the use of `strip` is less cryptic but sure, you solution works just as fine.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis using `strip` is not equivalent, though. You'd have to use `line.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: I am totally with you on switching from `strip` to `rstrip` but why provide arguments? Without any it should be cross-platform, right?

Comment: Because that would also strip any trailing whitespace and technically that's not equivalent to printing out trailing whitespace.